# Write to M25P80 Flash

Tags: drivers, embedded, qemu, device-tree

I am looking for a way to move data onto a Micron M25P80 Flash Card over SPI bus on a Xilinx Zynq 7100 emulated in QEMU. I am not sure which driver to use. I would like to use the Cadence SPI driver but I am not sure if that will work. I am trying to run my user space application on QEMU, and although I have specified that I want SPI included in my device tree, it does not appear as a device in the /dev/ directory.

Here is my device tree
    /dts-v1/;

```
/ {
    #address-cells = <0x1>;
    #size-cells = <0x1>;
    compatible = "xlnx,zynq-7000";
    model = "petaproject";

    chosen {
        bootargs = "console=ttyPS0,115200 earlyprintk";
        stdout-path = "serial0:115200ns";
    };

    aliases {
        serial0 = "/amba/serial@e0001000";
        ethernet0 = "/amba/ethernet@e000b000";
        spi0 = "/amba/spi@e000d000";
    };

    memory {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x40000000>;
    };

    cpus {
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x0>;

        cpu@0 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
            device_type = "cpu";
            reg = <0x0>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x3>;
            clock-latency = <0x3e8>;
            cpu0-supply = <0x2>;
            operating-points = <0xa2c2a 0xf4240 0x51615 0xf4240>;
        };

        cpu@1 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9";
            device_type = "cpu";
            reg = <0x1>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x3>;
        };
    };

    pmu {
        compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-pmu";
        interrupts = <0x0 0x5 0x4 0x0 0x6 0x4>;
        interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
        reg = <0xf8891000 0x1000 0xf8893000 0x1000>;
    };

    fixedregulator@0 {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        regulator-name = "VCCPINT";
        regulator-min-microvolt = <0xf4240>;
        regulator-max-microvolt = <0xf4240>;
        regulator-boot-on;
        regulator-always-on;
        linux,phandle = <0x2>;
        phandle = <0x2>;
    };

    amba {
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
        interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
        ranges;

        adc@f8007100 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-xadc-1.00.a";
            reg = <0xf8007100 0x20>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x7 0x4>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            clocks = <0x1 0xc>;
        };

        can@e0008000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-can-1.0";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x13 0x1 0x24>;
            clock-names = "can_clk", "pclk";
            reg = <0xe0008000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x1c 0x4>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            tx-fifo-depth = <0x40>;
            rx-fifo-depth = <0x40>;
        };

        can@e0009000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-can-1.0";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x14 0x1 0x25>;
            clock-names = "can_clk", "pclk";
            reg = <0xe0009000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x33 0x4>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            tx-fifo-depth = <0x40>;
            rx-fifo-depth = <0x40>;
        };

        gpio@e000a000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-gpio-1.0";
            #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x2a>;
            gpio-controller;
            interrupt-controller;
            #interrupt-cells = <0x2>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x14 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe000a000 0x1000>;
            emio-gpio-width = <0x40>;
            gpio-mask-high = <0x0>;
            gpio-mask-low = <0x5600>;
            linux,phandle = <0x4>;
            phandle = <0x4>;
        };

        i2c@e0004000 {
            compatible = "cdns,i2c-r1p10";
            status = "okay";
            clocks = <0x1 0x26>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x19 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0004000 0x1000>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            clock-frequency = <0x61a80>;
            i2c-reset = <0x4 0x2e 0x0>;
            pinctrl-names = "default";

            i2cswitch@74 {
                compatible = "nxp,pca9548";
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x0>;
                reg = <0x74>;

                i2c@0 {
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x0>;
                    reg = <0x0>;

                    clock-generator@5d {
                        #clock-cells = <0x0>;
                        compatible = "silabs,si570";
                        temperature-stability = <0x32>;
                        reg = <0x5d>;
                        factory-fout = <0x9502f90>;
                        clock-frequency = <0x8d9ee20>;
                    };
                };

                i2c@2 {
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x0>;
                    reg = <0x2>;

                    eeprom@54 {
                        compatible = "at,24c08";
                        reg = <0x54>;
                    };
                };

                i2c@3 {
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x0>;
                    reg = <0x3>;

                    gpio@21 {
                        compatible = "ti,tca6416";
                        reg = <0x21>;
                        gpio-controller;
                        #gpio-cells = <0x2>;
                    };
                };

                i2c@4 {
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x0>;
                    reg = <0x4>;

                    rtc@51 {
                        compatible = "nxp,pcf8563";
                        reg = <0x51>;
                    };
                };

                i2c@7 {
                    #address-cells = <0x1>;
                    #size-cells = <0x0>;
                    reg = <0x7>;

                    hwmon@52 {
                        compatible = "ti,ucd9248";
                        reg = <0x34>;
                    };

                    hwmon@53 {
                        compatible = "ti,ucd9248";
                        reg = <0x35>;
                    };

                    hwmon@54 {
                        compatible = "ti,ucd9248";
                        reg = <0x36>;
                    };
                };
            };
        };

        i2c@e0005000 {
            compatible = "cdns,i2c-r1p10";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x27>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x30 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0005000 0x1000>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        interrupt-controller@f8f01000 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-gic";
            #interrupt-cells = <0x3>;
            interrupt-controller;
            reg = <0xf8f01000 0x1000 0xf8f00100 0x100>;
            num_cpus = <0x2>;
            num_interrupts = <0x60>;
            linux,phandle = <0x3>;
            phandle = <0x3>;
        };

        cache-controller@f8f02000 {
            compatible = "arm,pl310-cache";
            reg = <0xf8f02000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2 0x4>;
            arm,data-latency = <0x3 0x2 0x2>;
            arm,tag-latency = <0x2 0x2 0x2>;
            cache-unified;
            cache-level = <0x2>;
        };

        memory-controller@f8006000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-ddrc-a05";
            reg = <0xf8006000 0x1000>;
        };

        ocmc@f800c000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-ocmc-1.0";
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x3 0x4>;
            reg = <0xf800c000 0x1000>;
        };

        serial@e0000000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,xuartps", "cdns,uart-r1p8";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x17 0x1 0x28>;
            clock-names = "uart_clk", "pclk";
            reg = <0xe0000000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x1b 0x4>;
        };

        serial@e0001000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,xuartps", "cdns,uart-r1p8";
            status = "okay";
            clocks = <0x1 0x18 0x1 0x29>;
            clock-names = "uart_clk", "pclk";
            reg = <0xe0001000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x32 0x4>;
            device_type = "serial";
            port-number = <0x0>;
        };

        spi@e0006000 {
            compatible = "cdns,spi-r1p6";
            reg = <0xe0007000 0x1000>;
            status = "okay";
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x31 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1a 0x1 0x23>;
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "pclk";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            num-cs = <0x4>;
            is-decoded-cs = <0x0>;

            flash@0 {
                compatible = "sst25wf080";
                reg = <0x1>;
                spi-max-frequency = <0xf4240>;
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x1>;

                partition@test {
                    label = "spi-flash";
                    reg = <0x0 0x100000>;
                };
            };

            spidev@0x02 {
                compatible = "spidev";
                spi-max-frequency = <0x124f80>;
                reg = <0x0>;
            };
        };

        spi@e0007000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-spi-r1p6";
            reg = <0xe0007000 0x1000>;
            status = "disabled";
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x31 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1a 0x1 0x23>;
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "pclk";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        spi@e000d000 {
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "pclk";
            clocks = <0x1 0xa 0x1 0x2b>;
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-qspi-1.0";
            status = "okay";
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x13 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe000d000 0x1000>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            is-dual = <0x1>;
            num-cs = <0x1>;

            flash@0 {
                compatible = "micron,m25p80";
                reg = <0x0>;
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x1>;
                spi-max-frequency = <0x2faf080>;

                partition@0x00000000 {
                    label = "boot";
                    reg = <0x0 0x500000>;
                };

                partition@0x00500000 {
                    label = "bootenv";
                    reg = <0x500000 0x20000>;
                };

                partition@0x00520000 {
                    label = "kernel";
                    reg = <0x520000 0xa80000>;
                };

                partition@0x00fa0000 {
                    label = "spare";
                    reg = <0xfa0000 0x0>;
                };
            };
        };

        memory-controller@e000e000 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            status = "disabled";
            clock-names = "memclk", "aclk";
            clocks = <0x1 0xb 0x1 0x2c>;
            compatible = "arm,pl353-smc-r2p1";
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x12 0x4>;
            ranges;
            reg = <0xe000e000 0x1000>;

            flash@e1000000 {
                status = "disabled";
                compatible = "arm,pl353-nand-r2p1";
                reg = <0xe1000000 0x1000000>;
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x1>;
            };

            flash@e2000000 {
                status = "disabled";
                compatible = "cfi-flash";
                reg = <0xe2000000 0x2000000>;
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                #size-cells = <0x1>;
            };
        };

        ethernet@e000b000 {
            compatible = "cdns,zynq-gem", "cdns,gem";
            reg = <0xe000b000 0x1000>;
            status = "okay";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x16 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1e 0x1 0x1e 0x1 0xd>;
            clock-names = "pclk", "hclk", "tx_clk";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
            enet-reset = <0x4 0x2f 0x0>;
            phy-mode = "rgmii-id";
            xlnx,ptp-enet-clock = <0x69f6bcb>;
            local-mac-address = [00 0a 35 00 1e 53];
        };

        ethernet@e000c000 {
            compatible = "cdns,zynq-gem", "cdns,gem";
            reg = <0xe000c000 0x1000>;
            status = "disabled";
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2d 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1f 0x1 0x1f 0x1 0xe>;
            clock-names = "pclk", "hclk", "tx_clk";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x0>;
        };

        sdhci@e0100000 {
            compatible = "arasan,sdhci-8.9a";
            status = "okay";
            clock-names = "clk_xin", "clk_ahb";
            clocks = <0x1 0x15 0x1 0x20>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x18 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0100000 0x1000>;
            broken-adma2;
            xlnx,has-cd = <0x1>;
            xlnx,has-power = <0x0>;
            xlnx,has-wp = <0x1>;
        };

        sdhci@e0101000 {
            compatible = "arasan,sdhci-8.9a";
            status = "disabled";
            clock-names = "clk_xin", "clk_ahb";
            clocks = <0x1 0x16 0x1 0x21>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2f 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0101000 0x1000>;
            broken-adma2;
        };

        slcr@f8000000 {
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-slcr", "syscon", "simple-mfd";
            reg = <0xf8000000 0x1000>;
            ranges;
            linux,phandle = <0x5>;
            phandle = <0x5>;

            clkc@100 {
                #clock-cells = <0x1>;
                compatible = "xlnx,ps7-clkc";
                fclk-enable = <0x1>;
                clock-output-names = "armpll", "ddrpll", "iopll", "cpu_6or4x", "cpu_3or2x", "cpu_2x", "cpu_1x", "ddr2x", "ddr3x", "dci", "lqspi", "smc", "pcap", "gem0", "gem1", "fclk0", "fclk1", "fclk2", "fclk3", "can0", "can1", "sdio0", "sdio1", "uart0", "uart1", "spi0", "spi1", "dma", "usb0_aper", "usb1_aper", "gem0_aper", "gem1_aper", "sdio0_aper", "sdio1_aper", "spi0_aper", "spi1_aper", "can0_aper", "can1_aper", "i2c0_aper", "i2c1_aper", "uart0_aper", "uart1_aper", "gpio_aper", "lqspi_aper", "smc_aper", "swdt", "dbg_trc", "dbg_apb";
                reg = <0x100 0x100>;
                ps-clk-frequency = <0x1fca055>;
                linux,phandle = <0x1>;
                phandle = <0x1>;
            };

            rstc@200 {
                compatible = "xlnx,zynq-reset";
                reg = <0x200 0x48>;
                #reset-cells = <0x1>;
                syscon = <0x5>;
            };

            pinctrl@700 {
                compatible = "xlnx,pinctrl-zynq";
                reg = <0x700 0x200>;
                syscon = <0x5>;
            };
        };

        dmac@f8003000 {
            compatible = "arm,pl330", "arm,primecell";
            reg = <0xf8003000 0x1000>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupt-names = "abort", "dma0", "dma1", "dma2", "dma3", "dma4", "dma5", "dma6", "dma7";
            interrupts = <0x0 0xd 0x4 0x0 0xe 0x4 0x0 0xf 0x4 0x0 0x10 0x4 0x0 0x11 0x4 0x0 0x28 0x4 0x0 0x29 0x4 0x0 0x2a 0x4 0x0 0x2b 0x4>;
            #dma-cells = <0x1>;
            #dma-channels = <0x8>;
            #dma-requests = <0x4>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x1b>;
            clock-names = "apb_pclk";
        };

        devcfg@f8007000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-devcfg-1.0";
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x8 0x4>;
            reg = <0xf8007000 0x100>;
            clocks = <0x1 0xc 0x1 0xf 0x1 0x10 0x1 0x11 0x1 0x12>;
            clock-names = "ref_clk", "fclk0", "fclk1", "fclk2", "fclk3";
            syscon = <0x5>;
        };

        efuse@f800d000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-efuse";
            reg = <0xf800d000 0x20>;
        };

        timer@f8f00200 {
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-global-timer";
            reg = <0xf8f00200 0x20>;
            interrupts = <0x1 0xb 0x301>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x4>;
        };

        timer@f8001000 {
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0xa 0x4 0x0 0xb 0x4 0x0 0xc 0x4>;
            compatible = "cdns,ttc";
            clocks = <0x1 0x6>;
            reg = <0xf8001000 0x1000>;
        };

        timer@f8002000 {
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x25 0x4 0x0 0x26 0x4 0x0 0x27 0x4>;
            compatible = "cdns,ttc";
            clocks = <0x1 0x6>;
            reg = <0xf8002000 0x1000>;
        };

        timer@f8f00600 {
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x1 0xd 0x301>;
            compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-twd-timer";
            reg = <0xf8f00600 0x20>;
            clocks = <0x1 0x4>;
        };

        usb@e0002000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-usb-2.20a", "chipidea,usb2";
            status = "okay";
            clocks = <0x1 0x1c>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x15 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0002000 0x1000>;
            phy_type = "ulpi";
            dr_mode = "host";
            usb-reset = <0x4 0x7 0x0>;
        };

        usb@e0003000 {
            compatible = "xlnx,zynq-usb-2.20a", "chipidea,usb2";
            status = "disabled";
            clocks = <0x1 0x1d>;
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x2c 0x4>;
            reg = <0xe0003000 0x1000>;
            phy_type = "ulpi";
        };

        watchdog@f8005000 {
            clocks = <0x1 0x2d>;
            compatible = "cdns,wdt-r1p2";
            interrupt-parent = <0x3>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x9 0x1>;
            reg = <0xf8005000 0x1000>;
            timeout-sec = <0xa>;
        };
    };
};
```

I am not sure if it would be easier to use spi-dev in the device tree and use that driver. I tried setting spi-dev up in the device tree but it does not appear as a device in QEMU. This may be a side-effect of QEMU however. I am also not sure if I would need to nest the M25P80 card under the spi-dev to be able to access it with the spi-dev driver.

It also looks like there are SPI drivers included under /sys

> root@plnx_arm:/sys/bus/spi/drivers# ls
>
> at25    m25p80

I am not sure how these guys fit into the equation either.